# What does dsaEncryption mean in X.509 certificates?

Tags: encryption, openssl, x509, dsa

I have produced a signing certificate with DSA keys, and it has the following field which made me curious:

Public Key Algorithm: dsaEncryption

AFAIK, DSA is not suitable for encryption. Then what does this stand for? Did they mean ElGamal encryption or what? I spent more than an hour searching in specifications, etc., still I don't know.

It is particularly interesting that if a certificate like this is fed to the openssl function EVP_PKEY_encrypt_old(), then it works (doesn't fail). I found this interesting, because in the source code I found, they only handle RSA encryption.

What is going on here?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why do you think DSA is not suitable for encryption?

Comment: e.g. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/why-dsa-cannot-be-used-for-encryption